# View State Information Hidden on Managed Packaged VF Pages

Tags: visualforce, viewstate, support

I have been attempting to get the View State information for my managed packaged VF page within a customers sandbox. The user I am logged in as does have **Development Mode** and **Show View State in Development Mode** enabled.

***Developer Console:***
View state tab is appearing but no information being shown. I do believe this is a known issue and SF are investigating. Please see [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000ePnfAAE) link on Success Community.

***Browser:***
Development footer does not appear for any managed packaged VF page I open.

Answer (score 2):

After contacting SF support I received a response which states that **SF do not support View State information for Managed Package VF pages** within a customers sandbox.

They have been willing to state this is **not** documented but their seniors are now investigating this issue.

In order for the developer to see any View State information for a Managed Package VF page they must request SF support to enable debug logs for that Managed Package.

I spent a couple of days looking into this and hope this post prevents others wasting their time.

Comment: have you tried using "Grant Login Access" option to your managed package's support team to see if that helps?