# Seeing the View State for a page in a managed package in customer orgs

Tags: apex, managed-package, governorlimits, viewstate

We have a managed package that we have installed in customer orgs. One of the pages shows the error below when loaded:
[image]

I know I can go to user settings and turn on "Developer Mode" and "Show View State in Development Mode" to see the view state on the page. The problem with that is that it doesn't show the view state for pages in a managed package.

A workaround I have found is to manually deploy the same page from Sandbox to Production but that takes time and is slow for iterations. On the other hand, I have no idea what is contributing to the view state so reproducing the error in a development environment does not guarantee the resolution of the issue in production. We also tried "granting locin access" to our support team with no luck.

So the question is:

Is there a way to see the view state of managed pages in customer orgs?

Comment: This looks like to be the same issue as this one here -- [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147902/view-state-information-hidden-on-managed-packaged-vf-pages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147902/view-state-information-hidden-on-managed-packaged-vf-pages)

Comment: @JayantDas looks like the same. The only difference is that the question you are referring to is in Sandbox while this question is concerned about production environment. Not sure if that is important in anyway?

Comment: I would think it to be the same scenario for sandbox vs. prod, not quite sure though. But your comment on the other link may be an approach, i.e., reach out to the support team of the managed package. Further, considering this is a managed package issue, it should be addressed by the app provider until it can be addressed locally and that it meets the requisite as outlined [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220957&type=1)

Comment: I did not find an answer to this. However, I deployed the code in the managed package from a sandbox to the production of the org that was having this issue and was able to see view state that way. It is a workaround but helped me get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, try optimizing the page by reducing the calls to non-transient variables or optimizing SOQL. Also, try if you can see breaking of your page through browsers console.

Let us know if you find something.

Thanks

Comment: This really does not answer the question. @Jorjani is not seeking suggestions about reducing the size of the view state.

Comment: Yes, agreed but it was just a workaround I felt could help

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce does not allow to view the VF view state size in Managed Package but through LMA access, you can view the packaged org logs in debug logs and identify the code optimization required in the VF.